# Android app - publish but not make it accessible through android market search

Tags: android, app-store

Here's the scenario i am trying to achieve:

1. Publish/have an app in the Android app store
2. However - i do *not* want it to be searchable through the android market search, etc.
3. The only way people can access the app is if i give them an explicit link to download

Is above possible? If so - how? All FAQs/instrucitons i have seen publish & make it searchable for the whole world - but i want it only accessible through #3 above.

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need to do this? I'm not an android expert but I'm sure googles system for getting you paid is quite secure? Publish it as a paid app?

Comment: The app is still in BETA - and i only want to share it with a select group of people (who i will send out links to). I do not want the general public to see the App in the Android market searches yet.

Comment: I would not put it on the market.  There is no current way to make an app private on the market.  I host all my beta projects on a dead end page on one of my sites.  The only way for a person to get them is through a very explicit link that I send them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this site https://www.push-link.com/, you can upload apk on your private account and only can be accessible thorough automatic generated link and QR code. This service contains  user notification on new versions and bug reports.

Comment: Will this work for devices that do not have the option to downloads and install apps from 'Unknown Sources' ?

Answer (score 1):

Two things that are problematic with the link to an APK approach:

1. Some of the devices out there (I m only aware of the Motorola Atrix) don't have the "Unkown Sources" option, meaning that this won't work on them.
2. You loose the ability to auto update the app if you want.

I would recommend adding a login process where only your users will have access to the actual application. This way, you still have the Market advantages and only those people can activate the application.
The main disadvantage is that the application will be open to search in the Market, but as far as I know, this won't be a problem since people will immediately uninstall it since they won't be able to activate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, what I do is, I dont upload the application to the Market and distribute it from my server.

I mean this is simple, sweet and it also saves my $25 for the market account...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Just publish the APK to your own website, then give the users the URL to the APK, they can download and install it directly. The only thing they'll need to do is ensure that Menu-Settings-Applications-Unknown sources is ticked.